# ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED not received when app is forced closed

Tags: android, apk, android-broadcast, android-update-app

I have a notification about new things added to my app. It registers a `BroadcastReceiver` and listens for `Intent.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED`. It works fine and I do receive it and can show my notification. It even works when I close  the app via recent tasks swipe. I see a new process being launched which receives the broadcast, however I've noticed there are cases where it doesn't get to my app.

1. When app is installed and never run before updating.
2. When app is force closed at any time and not relaunched before updating.

Why is that? I thought that when app is closed via recent task swipe its process gets killed and when you have no background services it should be dead as if you force closed it from Settings->Apps.